# same code is giving different output when used in main function and in user defined function even when the input is same

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, sorting

so, the question says, we have to sort an array using insertion sort algorithm and print the resulting array after each iteration with numbers separated by space.
please help me understand what is the problem. why it is throwing an error?

```
input: 1 4 3 5 6 2
```

```
def insertionSort2(n, arr):
    for i in range(1,n):
        small=int(arr[i])
        j=i-1
        while j>=0 and int(arr[j])>small:
            arr[j+1]=arr[j]
            j-=1
        arr[j+1]=small
        print(' '.join(arr))
        print('\r')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())

    arr = input().rstrip().split()
    print(' '.join(arr))

    insertionSort2(n, arr)
```

when I printed array in the main function, then the output was:1 4 3 5 6 2
but, when I was trying to print the array in the function insertionSort2
run time error occured.

```
File "Solution.py", line 30, in <module>
    insertionSort2(n, arr)
  File "Solution.py", line 19, in insertionSort2
    print(' '.join(arr))
```

TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, int found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arr` is a list of strings at the start of `insertionSort`. You then take an element and convert it to an int in line 3: `small=int(arr[i])`.

So `small` is now an integer and then it assigned into the list `arr[j+1]=small`.

Which now means that `arr` contains a mix of strings and integers. The `join` method is expecting all strings.